# UWP static binding failed

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I have a `DataGrid` with its `ItemsSource` bound to a static variable of type `ObservableCollecion<Music>`
 like this:

```
        ItemsSource="{Binding AllSongs, Mode=OneWay}"
```

This variable, called `AllSongs`, is declared in the same page as the `DataGrid`.

However, `DataGrid` is not showing the `Data` in the `AllSongs`. I have manually set this `MusicLibraryDataGrid.ItemsSource = AllSongs;` in the constructor. Why is this happening?

Another question is that, after I set it manually, Why modifications on the `AllSongs` like sorting do not reflect on the `DataGrid`? Meaning that the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` is not in sync with the `AllSongs`. Is it possible to make them in sync?

A possible solution for my second question might be registering a `CollectionChanged` event of `AllSongs` to do `MusicLibraryDataGrid.ItemsSource = AllSongs;` in it. Will this rebinding harm the performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know binding on static property is not allowed. 
What I would do is create a property on the class that reads from the static one.

It's been discussed here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e0e426ba-4feb-4571-b80b-7ba8818079b6/uwpstatic-property-binding?forum=wpdevelop